# Angular 7 - Virtual scrollbar resets the selected item in multiselect while scrolling

Tags: angular, angular-material, scrollbar

I have a multi select drop down with virtual scrollbar inside it.

**Html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="multiSelectControl" multiple [(value)]="selected" (openedChange)="openChange($event)">
    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="5" minBufferPx="200" maxBufferPx="400" [style.height.px]=5*48>
      <button (click)="selectAll()">Select All</button>
      <button (click)="clear()">Clear</button>
      <mat-option *cdkVirtualFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
    </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

The .ts file:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'test-proj';

  toppings = new FormControl();
  toppingList: string[] = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];
  selected: any;

  @ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport)
  cdkVirtualScrollViewPort: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;

  multiSelectControl = new FormControl();

  constructor() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 4000; i++) {
      this.toppingList.push('gjkgkf--' + i);
    }
  }

  selectAll() {
    this.selected = this.toppingList;
    this.multiSelectControl.patchValue(this.toppingList);
  }

  clear() {
    this.selected = [];
    this.multiSelectControl.patchValue([]);
  }

  openChange($event: boolean) {
    if ($event) {
      this.cdkVirtualScrollViewPort.scrollToIndex(0);
      this.cdkVirtualScrollViewPort.checkViewportSize();
    }
  }
```

I have added 4000 items in the dropdown. If I select the first 2 items and the last two items and scrolls, then the selection check on the first two items disappears.

Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: That's a bug in cdk/material :)

Comment: is there any workaround?

Comment: you should implement some custom `valueChange` method, which keeps track of what's been selected or not, but that's very tricky to do. I just tried for a while, but can't come up with a robust solution. You could always make a bug report. I've made a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-woaup6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) with the problem. The issue is that the `options: QueryList<MatOption>` in the `mat-select` does not contain the previous elements anymore, so the value of the option is discarded from the selection once you make a new selection

Comment: It already has a report here: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/15902

Comment: Simply add the selected options to your mat-select, not nice - but cheap work around. https://angular-mdgvwq.stackblitz.io (forked from Poul; rel: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54222316/536388)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a sort of workaround for the bug itself. It uses the `onSelectionChange` of the `mat-option` element. On top of that, it checks for changes on the options list as well, and selects if necessary. It's raw unoptimized code, but you'll get the idea:

```
@ViewChildren(MatOption)
options: QueryList<MatOption>;

constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.options.changes.subscribe(() => {
    let needUpdate = false;

    this.options.forEach((option) => {
      const selected = this.selected.includes(option.value);
       if (selected && !option.selected) {
        option.select();
        needUpdate = true;
      } else if (!selected && option.selected) {
        option.deselect();
        needUpdate = true;
      }
    });
    if (needUpdate) {
      this.cd.detectChanges();
    }
  });
}

onSelectionChange(change): void {
  if (!change.isUserInput) {
    return;
  }

  const value = change.source.value;
  const idx = this.selected.indexOf(change.source.value);

  if (idx > -1) {
    this.selected.splice(idx, 1)
  } else {
    this.selected.push(value);
  }
}
```

And this is the `mat-select`:

```
<mat-select [formControl]="multiSelectControl" multiple [value]="selected" (openedChange)="openChange($event)">
  <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="5" minBufferPx="200" maxBufferPx="400" [style.height.px]=5*48>
    <button (click)="selectAll()">Select All</button>
    <button (click)="clear()">Clear</button>
    <mat-option *cdkVirtualFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping" (onSelectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
</mat-select>
```

With a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufabzu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

---

Be aware though that if you have a dynamic lists which can update its contents, and a selection that has been made is removed from that list, it will still be selected, even though that should not be possible anymore

Comment: just a small issue I am facing that when I scroll,, numbers disappear. is it possible to control the scroll. like after 200, 500 comes. I have played with maxBufferPx but any suggestion wud be great

Comment: @Gauravsa you should increase the `itemSize`. I've updated my stackblitz and set it to 50. It doesn't disappear while scrolling, and it's still smooth

Comment: ok it seems to work. However if I select all and scroll down faster, all the elements doesnt get selected at once

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure to import ScrollingModule.

I believe the answer is to add a trackBy function to your *cdkVirtualFor

```
*cdkVirtualFor="let topping of toppingList; trackBy: trackByName; templateCacheSize: 0"

trackByName(index: number, item: string): string {
    return item;
}
```

If you have duplicate names then you could try tracking by index, but I prefer custom ids for each item. Something that would make them unique.

I would also add `templateCacheSize: 0` if your are dealing with dynamic data.